# Why mysql returns null although data is there?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Check out this: [image]

My SQL query is:

```sql
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID, SKU, SUM(Quantity) FROM orders, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN 01-05-2013 AND 11-05-2013 
GROUP BY SKU
```

And in my code, I am doing the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID, SKU, SUM(Quantity) 
FROM orders, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN {$from_date } AND  {$to_date }
GROUP BY SKU";
```

**I want to select data that falls between two values.**

`ShipDate` is a text field and not a date field. I checked the table, and it holds the data, but MySQL returns null.

Why? What I am doing wrong?

How can I update my PHP code?

This code:

```
"SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID, SKU, SUM(Quantity) 
FROM orders, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(ShipDate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN {$from_date } AND  {$to_date }
GROUP BY SKU";
```

is not working for me.

Please help me.

Comment: Is the ShipDate stored as a DateTime or as a Date?  If a DateTime, consider using >= and <= respectively.

Comment: @sgeddes ShipDate is a text field apparently

Comment: its text field , not a  `Date` field...

Comment: Then convert it to a date -- see answer posted below -- looks right.

Comment: Incorrect use of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: In case it hasn't been expressed clearly enough, store dates as dates using the DATE or DATETIME data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the text into a date

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID, 
       SKU, 
       SUM(Quantity) 
FROM orders, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(ShipDate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-11'
GROUP BY SKU
```

and add quotes around the date and rearrange the date to `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: thanks..works like a charm on sql, please see my updated question, not sure how to do it in PHP

Comment: Have a look at **Prepared Statements** and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

As ShipDate is text field so `BETWEEN` operator is not evaluated correctly in case of Text data so you query fails. Convert your Text data in to Date using `STR_TO_DATE()`